# add items to ListView on SlidingMenu from Main Activity

Tags: android, android-listview, slidingmenu

i want to add ListView to  slidingMenu in My application like G+ official application , i create layout , and add it to main activity with this code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // set action bar title


    // configure sliding  menu
    SlidingMenu slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, slidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    slidingMenu.setBehindOffset(120);
    slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);


}
```

but i dont know how to add ListView items from this activity ! can any body help me ?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well,
you would be better if you define the ListView (and the SlidingMenu) in your XML (in R.layout.activity_main) and then and with

```
ListViev lv=(ListView)findViewbyId(R.id.mylistview)
```

where mylistview is the id of the ListView  in your XML.

You can add the ListView programmatically:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
ListView lv=new Listview();
linearLayout.addView(lv)
```

I advice to use definition in XML.

Comment: i should use separate XML Layout for SlidingLayout and main activity layout , because it show sliding layout behinde of main activity

Answer (score 0):

there is an method called addHeadVIew，just try

Comment: Can you please add a link to addHeadVIew or provide a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

See what you need to do is create a View for your Sidebar layout using

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sliding_menu, null);
```

Then you can use this view to host your Listview as

```
Listview lv = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Now you can easily set an adapter for your listview like you usually do. One thing you need to remember is that now you cannot use **slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu)** since your listview is hosted by the View v change this line as

```
slidingMenu.setMenu(v);
```

and Hopefully everything will work.